# Correctly parse date string with timezone information

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, datetime-parsing

I'm receiving a formatted date string like this via the pivotal tracker API: "2012/06/05 17:42:29 CEST"

I want to convert this string to a UTC datetime object, it looks like python-dateutil does not recognize that timezone, pytz doesn't know it either.

I fear my best bet is to replace CEST in the string with CET, but this feels very wrong. Is there any other way to parse summer time strings to UTC datetime objects I couldn't find?

```
pytz.timezone('CEST')
# -> pytz.exceptions.UnknownTimeZoneError: 'CEST'
dateutil.parser.parse("2012/06/05 17:42:29 CEST")
# -> datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 5, 17, 42, 29)
```

Edit: After thinking about it again subtracting one hour is completely false as the corresponding timezone is also currently in summer time, the issue of parsing still stands

Comment: I'm not sure DST counts as a separate time zone for the purposes of date-time calculation. The date-time library should figure out whether DST applies for the given input and parse it correctly, I'd hope.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no real `CEST` timezone. Use `Europe/Paris`, `Europe/Berlin` or `Europe/Prague` (or another one) according to your region:

```
>>> pytz.country_timezones('de')
[u'Europe/Berlin']

>>> pytz.country_timezones('fr')
[u'Europe/Paris']
```

They are (currently) identical and all referring to `CEST` in summer.

```
>>> dateutil.parser.parse("2012/06/05 17:42:29 CEST").astimezone(pytz.utc)
datetime.datetime(2012, 6, 5, 15, 42, 29, tzinfo=<UTC>)
```

Comment: Thing is that dateutil creates an naive datetime object for me: ValueError: astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime

Comment: @Strayer - if you know you're dealing with CET/CEST only, you can `.replace('CEST', '+02:00').replace('CET', '+01:00')` before.

Comment: Yep, this is what I'm doing now. I can only hope that the API of Pivotal never decides to do something else or someone decides to change the timezone setting of the Pivotal API User.

Comment: Is there a way to just get an offset from string "CEST"?